# In Scala, fetched value of declared field cast to its class-declared type

Tags: scala, reflection, types, casting, field

I would like to ask how to achieve the following in Scala. Consider

```
scala> case class C(i:Int)
defined class C

scala> val c = C(1)
c: C = C(1)
```

Given a field of interest, in this case

```
scala> val fname = "i"
fname: String = i
```

we would like to retrieve the original value and type of field i in c.

A first, naive, attempt included the following,

```
scala> val f = c.getClass.getDeclaredField(fname)
f: java.lang.reflect.Field = private final int C.i

scala> f.setAccessible(true)

scala> f.getType
res3: Class[_] = int
```

However,

```
scala> val a:Int = f.get(c)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Object
 required: Int
       val a:Int = f.get(c)
                        ^
```

Put another way, how to fetch the Int value for i in c (*)

```
scala> :type -v case class C(i:Int)
// Type signature
AnyRef
        with Product
        with Serializable {
  val i: Int  <----------------------- (*)
  private[this] val i: Int
  def <init>(i: Int): C
  def copy(i: Int): C
...
```

and for not necessarily Int type, consider field j in D,

```
scala> case class C(i:Int)
defined class C

scala> case class D(j:C)
defined class D

scala> :type -v case class D(j:C)
// Type signature
AnyRef
        with Product
        with Serializable {
  val j: C
  private[this] val j: C
  def <init>(j: C): D
  def copy(j: C): D
...
```

Thanks very much...

**In Summary**

Given

```
scala> f.get(c)
res1: Object = 1
```

and

```
scala> f.getType
res3: Class[_] = int
```

how to get

```
val a = 1
```

where a is of type Int, and knowing the type only from f.getType.

Comment: How could you expect it to work without a cast if you're using reflection to get its value? The compiler has no clue about the type of a field named `"i"` (nor whether it actually exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *static type* of `f.get(c)` is `Object`, because it can be any class and any field. However, at the runtime it will return an `Integer` (the Java wrapper class for `Int`). You can cast it by using

```
f.get(c).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

or

```
f.getInt(c)
```

if you know in advance that you are calling for an `Int` field. If you don't, you can pattern match:

```
f.get(c) match {
  case i: Integer => ...
  case l: java.lang.Long => ...
  case s: String => ...
  // etc.
}

// actually compiles to same code, but avoids the need to use boxed classes
(f.get(c): Any) match {
  case i: Int => ...
  case l: Long => ...
  case s: String => ...
  // etc.
}
```

Note that the taken branch depends on the actual value of the field, not on its type; e.g. for `val f: Any = ""` the `case s: String` branch will be taken.

Or you can use `f.getType` to get its type and make your logic depend on that.

Comment: Many Thanks, Alexey; in this scenario though, the type would be _inferrable_ only from the class declaration...

Comment: A call to `f.getType` delivers `Class[_] = int` ; hence, how to cast it onto an Int.

Comment: With `asInstanceOf`, as said.

Comment: Thanks once more, Alexey; to ask how to tackle used defined types ?

Comment: This is going to depend on what you actually want to do. Again, if you know the type in advance, you can just cast to it; if you don't, you can use reflection to find out its methods, fields, name, etc.

Comment: `f.get()` returns `AnyRef`, so how does that pattern match compile? In Scala 2.12 this doesn't compile for me. Also, there can be a need to explicitly set the "private final" field to accessible, like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6756600/1080804

Comment: @ecoe Why wouldn't it compile? Are you perhaps using `Int` instead of `Integer` as in the answer?

Comment: `Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found: Boolean, required: AnyRef`. My case class has some fields that are boolean and some that are string. So perhaps this solution only works if all fields have same type? If that is the case, why pattern match when only 1 possible type exists?

Comment: You need `java.lang.Boolean` for the same reason you need `Integer`.

Comment: And also boxed types for other primitives.

Comment: @ecoe I've also edited the answer to show how to avoid need for `java.lang` classes.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov brilliant! I was matching on field.getType as a work around, but your approach is much cleaner. Thanks!