# Scala type casting

Tags: scala, reflection, types, casting, runtime

In Scala, given an Object

```
scala> f.get(c)
res1: Object = 1
```

and

```
scala> f.getType
res3: Class[_] = int
```

how to get

```
val a = 1
```

where a is of type Int, and where the type is known only from f.getType.

Comment: What is `f`? And what do you mean with "type is known"? Should it be known at compile-time/runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, details are found in question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21090203/3189923 .

Comment: The compiler does not know what class object `getType` returns, thus how should it build a real type out of it? This is based on runtime information which is not available at compile time.

Comment: From the info above, how to create an Integer with value 1, at runtime ?

Comment: Many Thanks @sschaef for considering this question! Daniel depicts I believe a similar idea in the following answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Say you have this:

```
f.getType match {
  case x if x ifAssignableFrom classOf[Int] =>
    val a = f.get(c).asInstanceOf[Int]
}
```

There are two problems with it. First, it uses `asInstanceOf`, which you should never do. Second, the scope of `val a` is the case statement. A slightly better approach would be this:

```
f.get(c) match {
  case a: Int =>
}
```

This is better, because `a` will only be an `Int` if it is *really* an `Int`. The information from `f.getType` is basically useless, because it might be true or not, while the actual type is always true.

Still, the scope is limited, and it really cannot be any other way. When you say `val a: Int = f.get(c)`, you are declaring *at compile time*, that `a` will *always* be `Int` from that point forward, until the end of its scope.

Meanwhile, the return type of `f.get(c)` and `f.getType` is information present at *run time*, that is, after the program has been compiled.

If you need to do this, use the second alternative, but, instead, try to find a different design that does not require this sort of thing.