# How to get field value?

Tags: scala

So I'm a newbie  using scala 2.11.7 and I have to get field's value, but I'm getting output:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class $anonfun$1 can not access a member of class Class with modifiers "private"
```

I tried to set accesiblility of the fields but isAccessible method keeps returning false. Here is what i tried:

```
var o: Class=new Class();
o.getClass.getDeclaredFields map(x=>x.setAccessible(true));
o.getClass.getDeclaredFields map(x=>x.get(o));
```

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756442/scala-class-declared-fields-and-access-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
o.getClass.getDeclaredFields map(x=> { 
   x.setAccessible(true)
   x.get(o)
});
```